# Flutter suddenly crashes with "out of memory" on build

Tags: flutter, memory-management

When I run my flutter build, normally everything works fine.
Today I suddenly got this message in my Debug console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A3003 in debug mode...
c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\zone.cc: 90: error: Ou
t of memory.
version=2.8.1 (stable) (Thu Apr 30 09:25:21 2020 +0200) on "windows_x64"
pid=10648, thread=3848, isolate=main(000001B2159F1AA0)
isolate_instructions=1b218db0000, vm_instructions=7ff6912b1010
  pc 0x00007ff69143e17b fp 0x0000002c120fe860 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x000000000000007f fp 0x0000002c120feb30 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace

c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\zone.cc: 90: error: Out of memory.
version=2.8.1 (stable) (Thu Apr 30 09:25:21 2020 +0200) on "windows_x64"
pid=13268, thread=11080, isolate=main(0000025A6968EAB0)
isolate_instructions=7ff6912b1000, vm_instructions=7ff6912b1010
  pc 0x00007ff69143e17b fp 0x0000006ad98fa730 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x0000006ad98fa9e0 fp 0x0000006ad98fa9e0 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
Exited (3221226505)
```

How can I find out what uses this much memory?

Comment: Could you give more context? Screenshot of the screen you're working on? Some business logic you're doing?

Comment: My pc seems to be the issue. I also got a "memory full" error while using chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the below step in Android Studio

1. **File-> Invalidate cache/restart.**
   Android studio got restarted and when run the command
   **Flutter run**
   the issue got resolved